# Riley Riddle #4: Approval

Tags: riddle

The front is a nice guy but shorter
Between, an Aussie straw's hindquarter
The tail is tragic when it blows
A bureaucrat's weapon - they're pros!

Hint 1:

> All clues involved, including the whole word, are between 2 to 5 letters long.

Hint 2:

> The reference to an "Aussie's straw" is a pop culture phenomenon. The "Aussie's straw" is two words, "hindquarter" means use the last word.  As for the suffix, well, it's true - just ask a rockstar!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The front is a nice guy but shorter

> ST - abbreviation of Saint

Between, an Aussie straw's hindquarter

> TAM -  the [Tim Tam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Tam) slam/suck - the practice of drinking a beverage through a Tim Tam.

The tail is tragic when it blows

> AMP - amplifier

A bureaucrat's weapon - they're pros!

> STAMP - bureaucrats wield stamps!

Title: Approval

> I hope this post and the included letters have your stamp of approval.

Comment: You got it! A Tim Tam Slam is a weird thing in Austrialia where they bite off each end of a tim tam and drink something though it like a straw.

Comment: @flashstorm Your explanation of "tim tam slam" is helpful only to those who (unlike me) know what a *tim tam* is.  Thank goodness for internet search.

Comment: Fair! For those who havn't searched like phoog, a tim tam is two thin malt wafers sandwiching a chocolate mousse and covered in chocolate.